# How to detect if a partition is FAT or NTFS or something else?

Tags: file-io, ntfs, fat32, fat

I am developing a low level program that will read a partition and I need to know if the files are under a FAT or NTFS or some other kind of file system type so I can load the appropriate library for dealing with the files.

This is an embedded software design so there won't be an Operational System to help me with the partitions access, so I need to figure how to handle the files myself, and I confess I am kinda lost where to begin with.

Comment: For NTFS vs FAT, you could check the boot sector: [NTFS](http://ntfs.com/ntfs-partition-boot-sector.htm) and [FAT](http://ntfs.com/fat-partition-sector.htm). Do you need to be able to work with Other or is it just a detect and skip type of thing?

Comment: I would like to be able to work with as many as possible, but I guess most people only use FAT or NTFS right?

Comment: @mFeinstein I´m a bit late, but *NO*, absolutely not.See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_systems . Even on the one single home computer I´m using just now and the equipment around, I have like ... 10 different FS in use.

Comment: not that much late haha, I was just referring to 90% of people out there